# Is it possible to compare Strings that are Numbers as if they were Numbers?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Is there a library out there that has a facility something like:

```
public static String Min(String first, String second)
```

If you pass it "200"/"300" it would return "200", for example?

I know there's a million ways that I can write my own, so I'm really not looking for help there -- just hoping to find out if it's a wheel someone else has already invented.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an odd situation for somebody to have actually wasted their time implementing it in a library -- it seems like bad practice to me. I would convert each of your strings to numbers and simply run them through `Math.min()`.

Comment: while i appreciate the contribution, i guess i disagree on the merit of said function. in an XML heavy application - where we don't really care about the underlying numeric type - it would be quite handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hack frequently used in programming competitions in the absence of leading zeros is to compare string's lengths first; if lengths are not equal, the longer string wins; otherwise, return the result of lexicographical comparing of the strings.

**EDIT** : Since you care mostly about re-usability of your solution, you would get the biggest "bang for the buck" if you implement your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). This would let you reuse the same implementation with standard Java classes. For example, you would be able to use your comparator with sorted maps, to do array and list sorts, binary searches, and so on.

Comment: +1 for the offer. i guess my thing isn't even so much the implementation chosen to do the compare as it is the re-usability of the solution. if i write my own i'll likely start it simple and try to avoid the "creative" options i have. thanks!

Comment: @MattFelzani If you care about reusability, implement your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). This way you'd be able to use the same implementation with standard Java classes. For example, you'd be able to use it in sorted maps, Array and List sorts, binary searches, and so on.

Comment: no you're right, and actually "implementing" the method is a totally different question. while i absolutely appreciate the help there my solicitation was more to see if someone else had already solved my problem. thank you.

Comment: marking as answer as this is the first and best response of those offered.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer.parseInt()` on each and compare that value, for example:

```
Integer.parseInt(first) > Integer.parseInt(second)
```

Mind you, if the string is **not** a valid integer, this throws a `NumberFormatException`, so be sure to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Well convert them to numbers, using `Integer.parseInt(String str)` and compare the numbers:) Not really a big wheel to reinvent;)

Comment: yeah, i'm on board here ... just hoping that a more streamlined solution was out there. even the casting is something that we have 1000s of times in the code. plus, that's how you do ints ... we get strings out of XML so it would be neat if a method could just figure out the underlying numeric type, promote each to the same, do the compare, return a string in response. as the developer i don't actually care what it's numeric type is under the covers.

Comment: @Matt Felzani - Can't you reuse the method you have written?

Comment: lol @Petar Minchev ... it doesn't exist. i cited that more asking if someone else had penned it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would cast the strings to numerical values prior to passing into the method, and convert the result back to a string for display.

Comment: agreed. but that code is in our code base 1000s of times. just trying to save some typing and standardize the logic (seem my comment in @Petar's response). thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any such library that has a suite of methods of this sort that use the `String` class but operate on them as numbers.  Nor should there be.  What would you expect the behavior of these methods to be if the strings are not valid numbers?

There *must* be a step somewhere that converts the strings into numbers.  This is a validation step that vets the string in case it is not a valid number.  It is a completely distinct function from that of *comparing* the actual numbers.  Combining the two operations into one will make it so these functions are doing way more work than they should and blatantly violate the single responsibilty principle.

I'm not sure why you want to operate on strings as numbers -- presumably because the strings coming in are supplied by the user.  Therefore, you must validate that input separately and then convert them into numbers, after which you will have the normal math functions available to you.

Comment: outstanding feedback and i'd probably mark this as the answer if i were trying to write the function. my post was more to discover if someone else had written it. however, that being said i fully expect an implementation would convert to numerics and throw an exception if the inputs are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you you are sure that the string is a number, you could prepare the string with a regex (eg. replace `,` with a `.` ...) and then parse them as double. You should cover most of the cases that way (assume you are not parsing hex values).